# EF One to One relationship creates new record each on each call to `SaveChanges()`

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, one-to-one

I have an EF model which enforces a `user` > `address` one to one relationship which trimmed down looks like this:

```
public class User 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int AddressId { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey(nameof(AddressId))]
  public Address Address { get; set; } = new Address();
}

public class Address 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using the a generic repository pattern but the same thing happens if I work directly on the EF context.

If I do this:

```
public void Create() 
{
  var user = new User();
  context.Users.Add(user);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get a user created in my DB with an attached `address` and both the `AddressId` and `Address.Id` property are set to a correct value.

However if I do this:

```
public void Update(int userId, String name) 
{  
  var user = context.Users.Single(x => x.Id == userId);
  user.Name = name;
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I look at the user after the `SaveChanges()` the name updates as expected but I have an entirely new `Address` record created in the DB and EF has incremented the `AddressId` property for the user to the new `Address.Id`.

This seems like I've made a basic error either in the schema definition, or in how I'm expecting things to work.

Can anyone shed any light on this? appreciate any thoughts.

**EDIT**

If I make the `AddressId` on the `User` a nullable int and then tweak the create method like this:

```
public void Create() 
{
  var user = new User();
  var address = new Address()
  context.Addresses.Add(address);
  user.Address = address;
  context.Users.Add(user);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Then things work as I'd expect.

Comment: Can you check whether the "Address" property in the "User" object in the "Update" method is filled in? And what other data is in that User object?

Comment: @Magicbjørn when I retrieve the user in the Update method, the user is filled in correctly, both the `AddressId` property of the user, and the Address object with a matching `Id`. After the `SaveChanges` the same user object has the `AddressId` incremented and and is now linked to a new `Address` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem at this row: `public Address Address { get; set; } = new Address()` - each time, when EF retrives `User` from database, it rewrites old `Address` to **completely new** one, that is why `AddressId` is changed and icremented. So, simply remove `new Address()`, EF will have done all work by itself:

```
public class User 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey(nameof(AddressId))] is redundant
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }// = new Address();
}

public class Address 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Organization> Organizations {get;set;}
}
```

Usage with **not nullable** `AddressId`:

```
public void Create() 
{
    var address = new Address()
    context.Addresses.Add(address);
    context.SaveChanges();

    var user = new User{ AddressId = address.Id };
    context.Users.Add(user);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I thought this might have been the issue as well, but removing the line unfortunately makes no difference.

Comment: Ok, try to rewrite your POCOs exactly like I shown above.

Comment: I would do that, but unfortunately the Address object is re-used in several relationships where it won't have a mandatory link back to a user so if I made that change, the other relationships would not map correctly.

Comment: Also, I only put the `AddressId` property in to explicitly name the FK, if I remove it, EF puts in an `Address_Id` column with the same mapping

Comment: It is because, your POCOs are not actual in one-to-one relationship, if you will try my code, EF will not create `Address_Id`. And i don't understand how `User` link can crash other relationship - it is self-contained.

Comment: It's because addresses aren't always linked to users, sometimes they are linked to organisations etc, so it would be correct for an address on an organisation to have a `User` property which would always be null. 
I think following your thoughts through though, I would possibly need to make the `User` an one to many on the `Person` and the `Organisation` and then just handle the creation in code.

Comment: Sure, at this case you should have one-to-many relationship, where `Address` is principal end.

Comment: I've just tweaked my Person entity and I'm sorry I misled I think you were right with the `new Address()` line being an issue. If I manually create an address and link them together in the `Create` method things work as expected and I no longer need the `new Address()`

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov I didn't spot that = new Address(), once I saw your answer, it was obviously definitely the cause.

Comment: I understood, why you did it: you wanted at first to create and save user and only then link address to it. But, as your relation was strict, you can't do it, so you added stub: `new Address` to supress FK exception and to override `Address` lately, but it caused side effect. At this case, you could create and save address at first and then link it to existed user or new one. Look at **Usage** section of my answer. It will work with not nullable `AddressId`.

Comment: Yeah your usage example is basically what I ended up with, but by setting the reference of the `Address` object I can do it in a single DB roundtrip, so I slightly prefer that version.

Comment: Sure, I just paid attention on right order of operations not their concrete implementation.